# fopen loops twice over the same .csv

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I have an .csv file to process with PHP. The file contains 3718 lines. At the end of the loop, I set a log message.
It's a Drupal site, but I'm sure this is just a PHP issue.

```
$counter = 0;
if($file_handle = fopen($custompath, "r")){
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        mb_naw_handling_parse_create($line_of_text[0]);
        $counter++;
    }

    fclose($file_handle);
    watchdog('NAW File Processed', $counter. ' accounts created or updated');
}
```

But for some reason, I get following log: `NAW File Processed 7437 accounts created or updated`. Which is almost, just 1 off, double the number of lines...

What can cause this issue?

Comment: If your CSV lines are longer than 1024 bytes, you might have this problem.... try using `$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle);` rather than `$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);`

Comment: Ok, I'll try that... But why is this causing the double result?

Comment: Double result? If a line is longer than 1024 bytes then you read the first 1024 bytes only in one iteration of the loop (incrementing your counter), then read the remainder of the line in the next iteration of the loop (incrementing the counter again)

Comment: Oh, I see... :-) Give me a second to implement this on the project! In the meantime add it as an answer!

Comment: It isn't guaranteed to be the problem yet, a test will tell you if it is or not; but it is a possible problem that would cause the effect of doubling the number of lines

Comment: No difference between both results... What else could cause this loop running two times?

Comment: Check for "double" line endings "\n\n" or similar